# How to fix an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'.?

Tags: t-sql

Hey I have this query

```
IF (select kmkood from or_arved_read where kmkood = '1' or kmkood = '14' or kmkood = '15' or kmkood = '6' )
    BEGIN
    SET @stat_vat = 21
IF (select kmkood from or_arved_read where kmkood = '2' or kmkood = '7' )
    SET @stat_vat = 12
```

But it returns `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'.`

how can i fix it?

Comment: If you want to check the existence of at least one record, you might try IF EXISTS(SELECT ... )

Comment: I want to put `@stat_vat = 21 where kmkood = 1 or 14 or 15 or 6` @sergiom

Comment: Is stat_vat a field of the table or_arved_read ? If this is the case what you need is an UPDATE statement. 
Otherwise, if @stat_vat is a variable, then adding EXISTS before the "(" will fix your booelan expression.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `IF` doesn't have a boolean expression. The subquery returns a value (or more accurately for this scenario will return many and cause a different error) for the column `kmkood`, but then you don't do anything with that value. What value does that column need? The format should be something like this:

```sql
IF (SELECT SomeColumn FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE... ) = 'SomeValue'
```

Also, if you have a `BEGIN` you need an `END` afterwards, which you don't have:

```
IF (SELECT SomeColumn FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE... ) = 'SomeValue'
BEGIN
    {Do several statements}
END
```

As, however, you are just doing a `SET` statement then you don't actually need the `BEGIN` and `END` statements.

I suspect what you are *really* after here, however, in an `EXISTS`:

```sql
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.or_arved_read WHERE kmkood IN (1,14,15,6))
    SET @stat_vat = 21;

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.or_arved_read WHERE kmkood IN (2,7))
    SET @stat_vat = 12;
```

You don't need all those `OR`s either, an `IN` works fine, and numbers shouldn't be in single quotes, so that makes things a bit shorter.